# C++ double* array, test allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, null

I have some doubt: I want to test whether some arrays, low and high, have been allocated before function call. The function begins with this test:

```
bool myMgr::compute(myInput *solvInput, double* low, double* high)
{
   if(high==NULL||low==NULL)
        return false;

   //...
}
```

Am I testing anything, am I testing it right?

Thanks and regards

Comment: `if( !high || !low )` looks better and does the job.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall If `high` and `low` are pointers.  Using the `!` operator on them is misleading and confusion.  His initial `if` is my preferred form, although I have some comprehension for people who prefer `if ( high == 0 || low == 0 )`.  (I don't agree with it, but it is an arguable position.)  And of course, if you're using C++11, it's `if ( high == std::nullptr || low == std::nullptr )`.

Comment: Pedantically, you're testing the allocation not before the call, but after it is called. The tests are inside the function body. Besides, it is not very practical (except in some very special cases) to test allocation failures: usually, you cannot do anything about them but abort everything. If it is anyway what you're going to do, why not just crash?

Comment: @James Kanze  why would I prefer `if ( high == 0 || low == 0 )` to my solution, what is different?

Comment: @fork0 my boss doesnt let me crash

Comment: @dlib What the compiler sees is identical.  _I_ prefer using `NULL` when dealing with pointers, but others disagree, on the grounds that `NULL` is misleading; it suggests pointer, but still has integral type.  (E.g. if you have a template function `f`, `f(NULL)` will invoke `f(int)`, and not `f(somePointerType)`.)  Of course, a good compiler will warn if `NULL` is used in a non-pointer context, which somewhat negates the argument against it.

Comment: @dlib: well, don't tell him :) signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_IGN)

Comment: @fork0 A program which crashes is always incorrect.  But in many cases, the simplest and best solution for out of memory is to install a `new_handler` which aborts with an error message.

Comment: @JamesKanze: incorrect is to have the condition when you crash. A crash if often much easier to debug (assuming you don't disable the core dumps) than `exit(1)`. Besides, you can always catch all crashing signals, provide a more or less useful report for post-mortem analysis and exit. Scattering `if (p != NULL)` checks around your code is certainly no improvement of it.

Comment: @fork0 Totally agreed.  A program which crashes is incorrect (by definition), but if a program is incorrect, it's usually best for it to crash as early as possible.  Masking programming errors is _not_ a good thing.  (Extensive use of `assert` _is_ a good thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing if the two pointers are not NULL, which is what heap allocators will return if  they couldn't allocate enough memory, but you can't make others assumptions beyond that :

- They could be `!= NULL`, but initialized by the user : double* ptr = (double*)5;
- They could or could not be "arrays" at all : you have no informations on the number of elements which were allocated.

Comment: Heap allocators raise a `std::bad_alloc` exception if they can't allocate the memory.

Comment: Indeed, but not necessarily: the operator `new` have a `nothrow` version which returns `NULL` instead of raising an exception. But anyway if an exception is raised either the program is aware of it (if it's catched) or the program crashes, before its `compute` function call. My point was to accentuate the fact that a check against the `NULL` value is not strictly equal to *the memory is allocated*.

Comment: There are several ways of avoiding the exception, but in the usual case...  Anyway, I was just taking issue with that one statement, not the entire answer.  As you say, there is _no_ way of really knowing whether a pointer is valid (although using the Boehm collector helps a lot).

Answer (score 1):

You mention allocation.  That is misleading; the usual allocators *never* return a null pointer.  They raise an `std::bad_alloc` exception if there is not enough memory.

Using pointers like this is useful if you're offering some sort of optional behavior; the client code can pass a null pointer to indicate that it doesn't need the functionality you're offering.  (Of course, the client code could do the test itself, and only call your function if the two pointers are non-null.  Which solution is preferable depends largely on context.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are doing is correct. But you must make sure that you have initialized the pointers to NULL during declaration(in the calling method) - otherwise, they may have junk values which would slip past this test.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of c++ (from c++11) you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`:

```
if(high==nullptr || low==nullptr)
```

And you have to be sure that the pointers are set to `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

If `nullptr` is not available, then what you are doing is fine, alternatively, you can do as *SingerOfTheFall* wrote in his comment.

Also, instead of using arrays and having to rely on pointers, you can user `std::vector`, which would allows you to have more information about the current state of the array, like its current size.

Comment: Setting a pointer to `nullptr`, `NULL` or `0` all have exactly the same effect.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, but you can't assign `nullptr` to an `int` by mistake, while you can with `NULL` and `O`.

Comment: It's certainly preferable to use `nullptr` if all of your targeted compilers support it.  But good compilers will warn if you assign `NULL` to an `int`.  (For obvious reasons, no compiler will warn if you assign `0` to an `int`.  That's one of the reasons why I prefer `NULL` to `0`.)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot check whether the pointers point to something valid or not.

Instead you could pass the arrays as references, this ensures that the function will receive at least initialized arguments however the best is to use vectors:

```
compute(std::vector<myInput> &solvInput, std::vector<double> &low, std::vector<double> &high)
```

or even better put low and high in a class if they are 1:1 with each other

```
compute(std::vector<myInput> &solvInput, std::vector<minmax> &lowhigh)
```